# 2001 Chevy 1500 Silverado 4x4

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, fast-idle

I got a 2001 had the 4.8 in it swapped to the 5.3 and programmed it run good for two days changed the idle air sensor and now when you crank it it sputter and rev up to 4000 rpm out the old one back in it and the same thing happened

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is it throwing any codes? Why did you put a new Idle Air Sensor (do you actually mean an Idle Air Control valve or IAC)? I've never heard of a Idle Air Sensor. There's an intake air temp (IAT) sensor. My initial bet is there's an issue with the wiring going to whatever you're talking about. Something which happened when you replaced the sensor originally.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something either happened with the program or a sensor went bad like a air temperature sensor or a mass air flow sensor most likely the idle air sensor went bad sometimes new parts fail I would start by replacing the idle air sensor first cuz that would be your cheapest bet otherwise it should be throwing a code on your dash and you should be able to plug a computer into it and see what the code says just to make sure that code would be right I would clear all codes start the truck and run it and see if it throws another code if it matches the same one that was there before most likely that your problem